# Cocoa pods lproj folders and storyboard are missing

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm creating cocoapod of framework project and it is uploading successfully. But when i try to install for cross check then i found that lproj folder and storyboard strings files are missing. what should i do in podspec so that my all files be pushed?

```
  s.resources = "MyFolder/**/*.{png, jpeg, jpg}"
  #  s.resource_bundles = "MyFolder/**/*.{lproj, storyboard, xib}"
  s.resource_bundles = {
    'MyFolder' => ['MyFolder/**/*.{storyboard,xib,xcassets,json,xcdatamodel,imageset,lproj}']
  }
```

Comment: can you show screen shot

Comment: added that code of podspec